# Hybridauth Facebook login on mobile devices using native app

Tags: facebook-login, hybridauth, socialauth, hybridauthprovider

I have a wordpress site using hybridauth to allow users to login with Facebook. However, on mobile devices, it opens a new mobile browser asking for the facebook login data.

Is there a way to use the native Facebook app on the iphone / android for hybridauth social login instead of opening a browser tab?

One way would be to have them download an iphone app that is just an iframe browsing my repsonsive website and then sign up.

Is there a better way e.g. using sencha touch or some jquery library?

Comment: I'm using hybridauth on Drupal and was asking myself the same. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I used cordova.js and integrate facebook login using openFB.js plugin.You can try these 
[openFB.js plugin](http://coenraets.org/blog/2014/04/facebook-phonegap-cordova-without-plugin/)

For me it works fine......